# Why setTimeout(function, 0) is executed after next operation, but not in the moment of calling?

Tags: javascript

I run this code in JavaScript:

```
setTimeout(function(){console.log("1");}, 0);
console.log("2");
```

But output is:

```
2
1
```

Why not vice versa?

Comment: Because set timeout adds the callback to the event queue... so the function will be called only after current execution thread is over

Comment: If it didn't work like that (and your running function could be interrupted in between lines), you'd run into all kinds of race conditions with asynchronous code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `setTimeout()` puts all the code in a queue, and then later based on the time, it executes. So you can see the list of procedures to execute as a line of queue. For the above code, you have:

1. `setTimeout`
2. `console.log(2)`
3. Callback Functions, *if any*.

   1. `console.log(1)`

So, first thing that executes is, initialize the timer. Secondly, the `console.log` gets executed and you see `2`. An interesting thing to note here is, [`setTimeout` waits at least for `4 ms`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#timers) before executing its callback function.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `setTimeout()` or one of its friends, its function is placed on a queue to be executed after all the current code has finished.

It should be noted that [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#timers) says the minimum time is clamped to `4`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply because the callback function of the setTimeout method is executed later.

1. setTimeout(..)

   Althought you specify 0 the callback function is not immediately executed. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/779785/2391070
2. console.log("2") // 2
3. setTimeout calls callback and console.log("1") // 1